# angularjs directive : $watch returns a string rather the object

Tags: angularjs, directive, watch

I can't get $watch to return me a Javascript object. It always me a string instead like:
"{'text':'Hello'}"

Here is my directive (CoffeeScript):

```
app.directive 'progressIndicator', ->
restrict : 'E'
scope : { progress : '@' }
link : (scope,element,attrs) ->
        scope.$watch 'progress' , (v) ->
            scope.curPrg = v
template :  '<label>In progress: {{curPrg.text}}' +
               '<progress></progress>'
```

And the HTML code:

```
<progress-indicator progress={'text':'Hello'}></progress-indicator>
```

I've tried attrs.$observe : Same behavior.

I've tried controller rather link : Same behavior.

What's wrong ? What's the best way to do it.
In the end, I want to able to do:

Comment: What does the compiled (to javascript) directive look like?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile): *`@` or `@attr` - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings.* Read the rest of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the scope you are linking. The `@` symbol links data as a string instead of as an object.

Instead try `=`, like such:

```
app.directive 'progressIndicator', ->
restrict : 'E'
scope : { progress : '=' }
link : (scope,element,attrs) ->
    scope.$watch 'progress' , (v) ->
        scope.curPrg = v
template :  '<label>In progress: {{curPrg.text}}' +
           '<progress></progress>'
```

Comment: = works if I put in the HTML file <progress-indicator progress=curprogress> and not <progress-indicator progress={{curprogress}}>. Why ?

Comment: You have made an angular directive, similar to ng-repeat or ng-click. Angular knows to take the string entered in progress="" and check the current scope for the data/function with the passed in name